# Add this Jquery Code to ReactJS (or rewrite the code for React)

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have this code:

```
$(function() {

    $('#login-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#register-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

I got it from: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/2qOB0

I want to add this to my React project, I read about ComponentDidMount but I don't understand it very much...I need a helping hand in this please?

```js
$(function() {

    $('#login-form-link').click(function(e) {
     $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
   $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
  $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();
 });
 $('#register-form-link').click(function(e) {
  $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
   $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
  $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();
 });

});
```

```css
.panel-login {
    border-color: #ccc;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin-top: 140px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading {
 color: #00415d;
 background-color: #fff;
 border-color: #fff;
 text-align:center;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading a{
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #666;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 15px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
 -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
 transition: all 0.1s linear;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading a.active{
 color: #029f5b;
 font-size: 18px;
}
.panel-login>.panel-heading hr{
 margin-top: 10px;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 clear: both;
 border: 0;
 height: 1px;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.15),rgba(0,0,0,0));
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.15),rgba(0,0,0,0));
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left,rgba(0,0,0,0),rgba(0,0,0,0.15),rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
.panel-login input[type="text"],.panel-login input[type="email"],.panel-login input[type="password"] {
 height: 45px;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 font-size: 16px;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.1s linear;
 -moz-transition: all 0.1s linear;
 transition: all 0.1s linear;
}
.panel-login input:hover,
.panel-login input:focus {
 outline:none;
 -webkit-box-shadow: none;
 -moz-box-shadow: none;
 box-shadow: none;
 border-color: #ccc;
}
.btn-login {
 background-color: #59B2E0;
 outline: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
 height: auto;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 14px 0;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border-color: #59B2E6;
}
.btn-login:hover,
.btn-login:focus {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #53A3CD;
 border-color: #53A3CD;
}
.forgot-password {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #888;
}
.forgot-password:hover,
.forgot-password:focus {
 text-decoration: underline;
 color: #666;
}

.btn-register {
 background-color: #1CB94E;
 outline: none;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
 height: auto;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 14px 0;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 border-color: #1CB94A;
}
.btn-register:hover,
.btn-register:focus {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #1CA347;
 border-color: #1CA347;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div className="panel panel-login">
              <div className="panel-heading">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-xs-6">
                    <a href="#" className="active" id="login-form-link">Login</a>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-xs-6">
                    <a href="#" id="register-form-link">Register</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
              </div>
              <div className="panel-body">
                <div className="row">
                  <div className="col-lg-12">
                    <form id="login-form" action="http://phpoll.com/login/process" method="post" role="form" style={{display: 'block'}}>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabIndex={1} className="form-control" placeholder="Username" defaultValue />
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabIndex={2} className="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group text-center">
                        <input type="checkbox" tabIndex={3} className name="remember" id="remember" />
                        <label htmlFor="remember"> Remember Me</label>
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="row">
                          <div className="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabIndex={4} className="form-control btn btn-login" defaultValue="Log In" />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="row">
                          <div className="col-lg-12">
                            <div className="text-center">
                              <a href="http://phpoll.com/recover" tabIndex={5} className="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                    <form id="register-form" action="http://phpoll.com/register/process" method="post" role="form" style={{display: 'none'}}>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabIndex={1} className="form-control" placeholder="Username" defaultValue />
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabIndex={1} className="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" defaultValue />
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabIndex={2} className="form-control" placeholder="Password" />
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" tabIndex={2} className="form-control" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
                      </div>
                      <div className="form-group">
                        <div className="row">
                          <div className="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                            <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabIndex={4} className="form-control btn btn-register" defaultValue="Register Now" />
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            <Link className="col-lg-3 back-about" to={'./'}>&lt;&lt; Back to HomePage </Link>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it!!!!

All what I did is,

```
npm install jquery
```

in the CMD / Terminal

and `import $ from 'jquery';` in the file

and added this:

```
componentDidMount() {
        $(function() {

    $('#login-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#login-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#register-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#register-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#register-form-link').click(function(e) {
        $("#register-form").delay(100).fadeIn(100);
        $("#login-form").fadeOut(100);
        $('#login-form-link').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

});

    }
```